# Project in CodeLite not compiling: null makefile

Tags: c++, visual-c++, makefile, mingw, codelite

I've installed CodeLite on my Win10X64 machine. While installing I received the following messages:

[image]

But after installing [MinGW-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/)

[image]

and clicking the scan button, I only get `Visual C++ 14 x86` and `Visual C++ 14 x64` as electable compilers.

Creating my first project:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I click *Build > Build Project*, I get the following build log and there are no .exe files created:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C ""C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul  Makefile"
====0 errors, 0 warnings====
```

When I click *Build > Run*, I get the following:

```
Working directory is set to: C:\Users\abadp\Desktop\xxx\yyy\Debug
Executing: cmd /C  call C:\Users\abadp\Desktop\xxx\yyy\Debug\yyy && pause
Program exited
```

And by clicking *Debugger > Start\Continue Debugging*, I get:

[image]

Comment: The official site of MinGW is http://www.mingw.org/ *Project in CodeLite not compiling: null makefile* - you confused, it's not error.

Comment: @S.M. by why isn't the `.exe` file created?

Comment: It looks like created. Your CodeLite can't find `gdb` which is another program from MinGW.